# How Do I Cancel A Nested Timer?

Tags: java, android

I have a two timers:

- theFirstCountDownTimer;
- theGraceCountDownTimer;

I have a service that uses these two timers where the theGraceCountDownTimer is nested within theFirstCountdownTimer. On the OnDestroy Method, I want to cancel both timers.

```
private CountDownTimer theFirstCountDownTimer;
private CountDownTimer theGraceCountDownTimer;
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.

    return null;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    Log.i("Running", "The Service");

    final SharedPreferences myPref = this.getSharedPreferences("testPref321", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    theFirstCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(myPref.getInt("seekBar", 10000) * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String myMilis = Long.toString(millisUntilFinished);
            Log.i("Timer One", "OnTick-" + myMilis);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Log.i("Timer One", "OnFinish");

            theGraceCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    String myMilis = Long.toString(millisUntilFinished);
                    Log.i("Second Timer!", myMilis);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    Log.i("Finished!", "Heck Ya!");

                }
            }.start();

        }
    }.start();


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
@Override
public  void onDestroy(){

    theGraceCountDownTimer.cancel();
    //This is the error

    theFirstCountDownTimer.cancel();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Additionally, I know the error is specifically with the line, theGraceCountDownTimer.cancel.

The error states:

```
Process: com.example.jackson.dmtapp, PID: 22854
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.jackson.dmtapp.TheService@8090f39: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.CountDownTimer.cancel()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3479)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap27(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.CountDownTimer.cancel()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.jackson.dmtapp.TheService.onDestroy(TheService.java:93)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3462)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap27(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: `cancel()` both timers with a check for `null`. Have you tried it ?

Comment: I tried that and it worked! I thought that since I had established the countdown variables that they wouldn't be null, but this worked wonderfully. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as right!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `cancel()` on both timer. Since you initialize `theFirstCountDownTimer` inside  `onStartCommand()` so it can not be null. But `theGraceCountDownTimer`  can be null as it initialize after `theFirstCountDownTimer` finished .

```
@Override
public  void onDestroy(){
    if(theGraceCountDownTimer!=null)
    theGraceCountDownTimer.cancel();
    theFirstCountDownTimer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```